# ansible: why I cannot use {{ ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_release'] }} in playbook

Tags: ansible

I have ansible task run on localhost like this

```
  - name: add docker repository
    apt_repository:
      repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian {{ ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_release'] }} stable"
      state: present
      filename: docker-ce
```

I wish to use variable `ansible_facts['ansible_distribution_release']` to get the os distribution name, in my case, it should be buster. But it runs into an error like this

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_distribution_release'

I tried to  use `{{ ansible_distribution_release }}` directly, and it works

```
repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable"
```

Then I thought I should only access the facts directly, not access it as a key of the variable ansible_facts, but then I read the official document, I see use cases like

`{{ ansible_facts['devices']['xvda']['model'] }}`

It make me suspicious there is something wrong about my understanding of ansible variables

I've tried to not quote `ansible_distribution_release` in the `[]`, ie, `ansible_facts[ansible_distribution_release]`, but without luck

I run command below

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution_release"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution_release": "buster"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

thus proved there did have an attribute named `ansible_distribution_release` under `ansible_facts`.

Any help will be appreciated

---

udpate: 
I use instructions show below

```
- name: debug                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  block:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    - debug:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        var: distribution_release                                                                                                                                                                        

    - debug:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        var: ansible_distribution_release                                                                                                                                                                          

    - debug:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        var: "{{ ansible_facts.keys() }}"                                                                                                                                                                          
  tags: show
```

and find out `distribution_release` is not defined,  `ansible_distribution_release` can be directly accessed, but there is no such key as `ansible_distribution_release` in ansible_facts, but there do have a key named `distribution_release`. this is difference from the out put from

```
ansible localhost -m setup
```

the documents says

> INJECT_FACTS_AS_VARS
>
> Facts are available inside the ansible_facts variable, this setting
>   also pushes them as their own vars in the main namespace. Unlike
>   inside the ansible_facts dictionary, these will have an ansible_
>   prefix.

It seems I can access facts in the mainspace without the ansible_ prefix

Comment: You've said *"{{ ansible_distribution_release }} ... works"*. What is your problem?

Comment: @VladimirBotka sorry for not explain my confuse clearly. I thought I should only access the facts directly, not access it as a key of the variable ansible_facts, but then I read the official document, I see use cases like

`{{ ansible_facts['devices']['xvda']['model'] }}`

It make me suspicious there is something wrong about my understanding of ansible variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at all variables available to the host (localhost in this case)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost
```

The debug tasks below are equivalent

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_facts['distribution_release'] }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_distribution_release }}"
```

See [Caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts)